# Regex to match anything between parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I'm using regex to replace a specific pattern with a more simple one.

I need to take all characters, white space, from between two parentheses and use them in a capture group. However, it is possible for the characters between the parentheses are also parentheses.

Here are two examples of what I am trying to match:

```
.message("vel pharetra est urna eget justo. Nunc in dignissim velit. {} "
        + error.getMessage().getProperty())
.build().log();   

.message("Key : " + oldEntry.getKey() + " and Value: " + oldEntry.getValue())
    .build()
    .log();
```

My current regex: `\.message\(([\S\s]+?)\)[\S\s]*?((\.log\(\))|(\.build\(\)))\;`

It matches simple patterns when there are not parentheses in the message. But when there are parentheses, it stops the capture group at the first closing parenthesis. I'm sure this is because I'm using `+?` but I'm not sure how to specify that the search should continue.

I've created this regexr with a few examples. http://regexr.com/3h15u

Comment: Please tag a language.

Comment: In your two examples, what do you want to match? The argument to `message`, or everything from `.message` up to `log()`?

Comment: Im just looking superficially but according to the MDN, using ? after *, +, ?, or {} makes the capture group nongreedy...

Comment: I'm technically using the regex replace feature in Intellij and can't find a reference to what implementation they use.

Comment: @tobias_k the argument to `message`

Comment: @slackOverflow yes it is, but if i make it nongreedy it matches everything because of `[\s\S]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
\.message\((?s)(.+?)\)\s*(?:\.(?:log|build)\(\)\s*)+\s*;
```

Text between `(` and `)` is being captured in captured group #1

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VurEaf/4)

In Java use:

```
final String regex = "\\.message\\((?s)(.+?)\\)\\s*(?:\\.(?:log|build)\\(\\)\\s*)+\\s*;";
```

Comment: This is matching the message argument correctly, but I also need to it match .log or .build at the end (right now if it encounters one or the other it stops.) I need to match the whole thing for my replace to work.

Comment: Awesome, and regex101 is probably going to be my default tool now, thanks!