# Regex to match anything inside a specific function

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm trying to extract all the queries from a PHP file. I use PHP reflection to retrieve the content of a method.

When I use reflection the string looks a bit like this:

```
        DB::statement('\n
            ALTER TABLE `activity` \n
            ADD `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL\n
        ');\n
        DB::statement('\n
            ALTER TABLE `activity_recurrence` \n
            ADD `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL\n
        ');\n
```

I'm trying to capture anything inside the `statement()` function. I've been trying a lot of different regex options but I'm unable to crack the case.

I'm now using this regex: `()\(([^)]*)\)`. It grabs anything between parenthesis but does not check if it has a `statement` suffix. I've been playing around with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892835/regex-to-match-anything-between-parenthesis), but I don't get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I doubt this is possible in a robust manner using a regular expression. Reason is that such expressions are limited in what complexity they can actually process. That is a basic fact from complexity theory and artificial language theory. You would probably be more successful iterating over all those statements and using a basic string search algorithm looking for the first and the last opening / closing bracket.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not check if it has a `statement` suffix ?

Comment: Regex isn´t the right tool for this. Depending on what exactly your issue is, it may be doable though, itś just not very reliable. Is your issue that your current pattern also matches `DB::foobar(...)` lines and not just `DB::statement(...)` ? or is the issue that some of the SQL contains `(` and `)` characters and you want those not to be captured separately ?

Comment: @Raxi yet it's exactly that. See a statement like this I will not get the preferred result:

`     DB::statement("
            INSERT IGNORE INTO settings (settings_group_id, `key`, value)
            VALUES (1, 'default_country', 'NL'),
            (9, 'activity_external_link', NULL);
        ");`

Comment: Yea that unfortunately takes using regex off the table. Do the function bodies (that you've extracted using reflection) only contain `DB::statement(...)` lines ? or do they also contain other code ? And does the `DB::statement` function only take a single string argument, or is it more complex ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to anything inside the statement function, you might use a recursive pattern with 2 capture groups.

Then you can take the group 2 value.

```
\bDB::statement(\(((?>[^()]++|(?1))*)\))
```

**Explanation**

- `\bDB::statement`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(` Capture **group 2**

    - `(?>[^()]++|(?1))*` Atomic group, match either 1 or more chars other than parenthesis, or recurse the first subpattern using `(?1)`
  - `)` Close group 2
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNLx4x/1).

**Note** that can still be a brittle solution as you want to match sql statements.

Comment: Thanks, this works very good! I will set this answer as the accepted answer because the question was to have regex and not a PHP function.

Answer (score 1):

So arkascha set me in the right direction. Below is a vanilla PHP solution.

```
 /**
 * Get everything between 2 string parts
 *
 * @param  string  $body
 * @param  string  $startString
 * @param  string  $endString
 * @return array
 */
public function findBetween(string $body, string $startString, string $endString): array
{
    // Create an array where we can store everything
    $result = [];

    // Clean-up the string a bit
    $body = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $body));

    while (true) {
        // Find the first occurrence of the start string
        $start = strpos($body, $startString);

        // If we can not find any recurrence of the start string we break-out of the loop
        if (! $start) {
            break;
        }

        // The start is actually the first occurrence + the length of the start
        $start = $start + strlen($startString);

        // Find the end of the string
        $end = strpos($body, $endString);

        // Add anything in between the start and end inside the array
        $result[] = substr($body, $start, ($end - $start));

        // Chop the first part of the body
        $body = substr($body, ($end + strlen($endString)));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

In my case I will be using it like this:

```php
findBetween($body, 'statement(', ');');
```